# How to create one query that pulls data from multiple tables in Access?

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to create one query that asks for customer ID. That ID is then used to find the customer in one of 8 tables and return all rows for that customer that contain data. Is that possible to do? I have tried a union query, but all tables have different columns and column names, so that's not possible.

Thanks

Comment: What is youir goal? What tables are involved (name and columns). Sounds like wrong [normalization](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/283878/description-of-the-database-normalization-basics). You can use `UNION`. Just create blank columns if they are missing in a table (`SELECT myField, '' as blankField FROM myTable`). Column names are set by the first select staement, the following are named the same. Alternative `LEFT JOIN`the tables on custID what leads to column for each field but multiplied data if CustID is not unique in tables..

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use the query wizard. It will walk you through the necessary steps to connect different tables. The most important thing is that you have two columns with matching values, the name of the columns does not matter.